# Edit data in sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, mac-address

I got 3 problem to ask:

Firstly, I'm writing an android apps. But there is strange issue happens to me. 
At the beginning the app, I check if variable NUMBER_PROVIDED is "NO" (default value), I will open another activity by

```
intent = new Intent(this, InputMobileScreen.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_MOBILE);
```

After that, I need to provide my phone number in order to process. Then I will update a variable name NUMBER_PROVIDED from "NO" (default value) to "YES". I stored this value into a static variable and also write it to SharedPreferences.

Here my code for update global static variable:

```
MainActivity.NUMBER_PROVIDED = "YES";
```

and for update value in SharedPreferences:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();                
 editor.putString(getString(R.string.NUMBER_PROVIDED), "YES");                
 editor.commit();setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            finish();
```

After the editing in SharedPreferences, I call editor.commit(), setResult() and finish the input activity to come back to mainactivity. 
The app run smoothly on my devices (ASUS zenphone 5, android 4.4) but on HTC mini, it looks like that the commit did not success? I don't know why? and how to make the activity.finish after the commit() in the SharedPreferences is total complete

Secondly, in my app, I have to call one function to get MAC address of WiFi as following:

```
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = info.getMacAddress();
    if (macAddress == null)
    {
        macAddress = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
    }
    return macAddress;
```

On my devices, I got my MAC address every time, but in some other devices (I have logs in my app), sometimes it can not get the MAC address (return "00:00:00:00:00:00"). How to solve it?

Thirdly, When I'm at input mobile activity (names InputAcitity). I press home button to the home screen of the mobile, after that I re-click my app's icon launcher in order to be back to the app. But the screen shows that I in MainActivity (not in InputActivity anymore). It happens only in some specific devices, not all, I don't know that although I called startActivityForResult from MainActivity to open InputActivity

any suggestion is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Use finish() or context.finish() to close activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For `editor.commit()` issue in certain devices; there are three ways you can try to resolve

   i) try to use `editor.apply()`

   ii) call `finish()` in a `Runnable()` thread inside `handler()` with `postdelayed()` for few milli seconds

   iii) try to use `AsyncTask` with performing commit action inside `doInbackground()` and actvity's finish action in `onPostExecute`

Comment: sorry, I'm just newbie in android programming. So could you give me an example about it for the second and the third point?